# How can I find the Nash equilibrium for this game?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

*Sorry for my English, I am French but i couldn't find help on the French website (so I am here).*

I have a question about this two-player game:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
 & y_1 & y_2 \\
\hline
x_1 & a,0 & a,0 \\
x_2 & 1,-1 & -1,1 \\
x_3 & -1,1 & 1,-1
\end{array}
$$
When $a<0$ and $a>1$ it's easy because using domination we can find the Nash equilibrium (mixed), but when $0 \leq a \leq 1$ this is more difficult.

If $(p_1, p_2, 1-p_1-p_2)$ is the strategy of the player $1$ and $(q, 1-q)$ the strategy of the player $2$, by the indifference theorem for player $1$ I have
$$
E(x_1) = E(x_2) = E(x_3) \iff a = 2q-1 = -2q+1
$$
and for player $2$ I have 
$$
E(y_1) = E(y_2) \iff -p_2 + (1-p_1-p_2) = p_2 - (1-p_1-p_2)
$$
**What is the Nash equilibrium (mixed and pure) of this game for $0 \leq a \leq 1$?** I can't solve this equation...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Don't worry about the language: if your post's meaning is understandable, someone will likely edit it to make it more readable. You could also post it in French and ask (maybe in a comment) if someone can translate it for you. Also, please take some time to [learn how to write math here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you A.P. for your help. I am new here but I will learn.

Comment: Anybody can help me ? Please i need help

Comment: Please note that almost all I know about game theory is the minimax algorithm; in particular I don't know anything about finding mixed equilibria. On the other hand, I think that if $a>0$, then $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_1,y_2)$ are pure equilibria for your game, because $x_1$ guarantees that the first player will always win something while $x_2$ and $x_3$ don't.

Comment: Thank you A.P. but any mixture of probabilities between $y1$ et $y2$ is a best answer, no ?. So with $y1=0.2$ et $y2=0.8$ $E(x1) = a$, $E(x2) = -0.6$ and $E(x3) = 0.6$. Why $y1$=$y2$=1/2 whereas these two columns are symetric ?

Comment: I opened my comment with "I don't know anything about finding mixed equilibria" for that very reason. I told you all that I could think of, which isn't much...

Answer (score 0):

First, let's restrict further to $0\lt a\lt1$, since for $a=0$ we can replace any $x_1$ component in the strategy by a corresponding equal mixture of $x_2$ and $x_3$, and for $a=1$ $x_1$ dominates both of the other strategies.

With $a\gt0$, your first equation has no solution, since the right-hand equality implies that $2q-1$, and thus $a$, is $0$. That shows that there's no mixed equilibrium with full support on all of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

From the symmetry of the situation, $q=\frac12$ seems like a sensible candidate for a mixed equilibrium. This results in $x_1$ being strictly preferable to $x_2$ and $x_3$, and conversely, if the row player plays $x_1$, the column player is indifferent between $y_1$ and $y_2$. So the row player playing $x_1$ and the column player playing $y_1$ and $y_2$ both with probability $\frac12$ is a mixed equilibrium. In fact any $q$ with $a\ge\left|2q-1\right|$ yields an equilibrium together with $x_1$.